# Must the negative of a negative semidefinite/definite matrix be positive semidefinite/definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Must the negative of a negative semidefinite/definite matrix be positive semidefinite/definite? More generally, is there any relationship between positive and negative semidefinite/definite matrix?

Comment: Yes, this is immediate.